# How to find an element in a sorted array such that all the elements after it are greater than a given value?

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search

I tried to implement it by modifying the binary search algorithm.

```
int search(int *a, int start,int end,int sum){
int s=start,e=end-1,m;
while(s <= e){
    m=s+(e-s)/2;
    if(a[m] == sum){
        return m+1;            
    }
    else if (a[m] < sum) {
        s = m + 1;
    }
    else {
        e = m - 1;
    }
}
return m;}
```

Whats wrong with the above  algorithm?

Comment: You mean sum of all the elements after it is greater than the given value? or each element should be greater by its own? can you give a simple example?

Comment: What input leads to _wrong_ result, then?

Comment: "An" element? Since the array is sorted then if element X satisfies the condition then all elements that come after X also satisfy the condition. The last element of any array might also satisfy this: the (zero) elements that follow it are all greater than any value you choose. The question needs to be specified more strictly.

Comment: The function is intended to return an index of the array such that all the values (not sum of all the values) starting from that index are greater than the given value (sum in case of above fun).
For ex :
If my array is [3, 10, 17, 21, 24, 28, 32, 35, 37, 42, 45, 50]
and search for 44 i.e. call the fun as search(a,0,11,22), the result is 9 (ie 42 in array) however it should be 10 (ie 44 in array).

Comment: Have you traced your program by any debugger, then?

Comment: I think something is wrong with the logic, but I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: Your code may not give the correct answer if there are multiple entries of value = sum. Also, the boundary conditions need to be checked.

Comment: What is it supposed to output if all the elements are greater than the particular value?

Comment: "result is 9" --- [Doesn't seem to be the case](http://ideone.com/jS6S0w).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int search(int *a, int start,int end, int sum) {
    int s = start, e = end - 1, m;
    while(s <= e) {
```

simpler is

```
    // m=s+(e-s)/2;
    m=(s+e)/2;
```

you have to keep looping, maybe there are repeating elements

```
//            if(a[m] == sum){
//                return m+1;            
//            } else
```

note the condition changed to `<=`

```
//      if (a[m] < sum) {
        if (a[m] <= sum) {
            s = m + 1;
        }
        else {
            e = m - 1;
        }
    }
```

have to return `s` here

```
//  return m;
    return s;
}
```